# If i create a map with jvectormap hide() it, change my window width, then show() it, it will scale itself to be tiny

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I created two maps, one is shown and one is hidden. I have an option to choose the other map, which will hide the current one and show the other.

Here is the page load:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmzV1.jpg

Here is how it looks if I change my window size even a pixel:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slo2z.jpg

If I don't change the window size, switching between the two is fine.
When changing window size, the one currently in view will scale with the window (I put its width/height as a percentage of its parent) and will will as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: If I resize the window when it's tiny, it will scale itself back to fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how jvectormap works with % sizing but I decided to go about another way to do this.

Instead of the hiding/showing from jquery, I changed the z-index to move the map of interest to the top (higher z-index), essentially emulating the jquery hide/show behaviour. Doing this, I had to change their positioning to absolute and put them into a container so that they can be layered on top of each other.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I change some code in "wordl-map.js" and my same problem has been resolved. in line 91: 
when this.container has been created, you must set you width instead of '100%' value. I write this.params.container.width() and this.params.container.height() instead of '100%' value. Because I want to set container`s width to the map.